# can't create network instances to communicate outside world. Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

Tags: networking, openstack

i am install packstack on centos 7 server on virtual box and trying to make the create network instances to communicate outside world.

by using this command:

```
neutron net-create external_network --provider:network_type ﬂat --provider:physical_network \ extnet --router:external
```

The error message :

> Discovering versions from the identity service failed when creating the password p                                                                             lugin. Attempting to determine version from URL.
>   Unable to establish connection to http://192.168.0.11:5000/v3/auth/tokens: HTTPCon                                                                                 nectionPool(host='192.168.0.11', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/au                                                                                 th/tokens (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errn                                                                                 o 111] Connection refused',))

Comment: Connection refused means port 5000 is not listening on that IP.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz thank you for the reply, so in this case what should i do ? change the Port?

Comment: Make sure the port is listening on that IP and adjust accordingly. Hope this helps.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz so, how i can make it ?

Answer (score -1):

Check your `httpd` service with:

```
systemctl status httpd.service
```

It should be in "running" state.